# kAXVisibleCharacterRangeAttribute ignores app's top bar

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I need to get the visible range of the text on an app using `kAXVisibleCharacterRangeAttribute` to draw NSPanel on the screen.

But it doesn't cover the app's top bar and gives a text range that starts from index 0 even though I have scrolled and the text is not visible.

[image: Gives location start from index 0 of the text range that is not visible]

code:

```
func getVisibleCharacterRange()->CFRange?{
        var visibleCharacterRange: AnyObject?
        
        let errorType: AXError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
            self,
            kAXVisibleCharacterRangeAttribute as CFString,
            &visibleCharacterRange
        )
        
        if(errorType == AXError.success){
            let v = visibleCharacterRange as! AXValue
            precondition(AXValueGetType(v) == .cfRange)
            var range = CFRange()
            let done = AXValueGetValue(v, .cfRange, &range)
            precondition(done)
            return range
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

On Microsoft Word:
[image: Same on Microsoft Word]

Workaround: get the **INITIAL** CGrect of the text area and keep track of window resize and window moved

Comment: It might be a bug. What is the question?

Comment: @Willeke I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or if it is a bug.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. Which app? What is 'self'?

Comment: @Willeke MacOS, swift app. Self is an AXUIElement instance

Comment: This might very well be a bug, but the question is still pretty clear: "Is this supposed to happen, and if so, is there an alternative that excludes this top bar area?" In any case, I think the Apple forums might be a better place for this, to get their input on whether this is expected behaviour or not, if a bug if it's not, and see if there are any workarounds.

Comment: @CloudWave I wonder if you can use a combination of `kAXPositionAttribute` and `kAXSizeAttribute` to get the text view's frame, and then clip out any of your red highlights that don't fall into that frame. Though I haven't tried this, and it's entirely possible that the system considers the part behind the toolbar to also be part of the position and size of the text view.

Comment: No, this is not supposed to happen. If the range is always the same then the top bar isn't the problem. Is this issue reproducible with other apps?

Comment: @Alexander I have asked this on Apple Dev Forum and they want me to ask on Feedback Assistant but I know it is basically a feedback blackhole. Nothing comes back until now.

Comment: @Willeke Yes on Microsoft Word

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize the Notes app. Your code works for me. Are you sure `self` is the correct `AXUIElement`?

Comment: @Willeke yes I checked its role, it is a AXTextArea.

Comment: @Alexander After getting its position using kAXPositionAttribute, I notice that the y-axis of the text area's origin decrease (goes up) when I scroll to the bottom. That's why it always contains the CGRect of the text when I do CGRectContainsRect. But this sounds weird?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. The range doesn't always start at 0 but it's wrong. I think it's a bug.

Comment: @CloudWave hmmmm is it possible to get the area of the clip view that’s clipping the scroll view with the text view in it?

Comment: @Alexander my workaround is to get the *INITIAL* CGrect of the text area and keep track of window resize and window moved.